# how to retrieve the value of a component of a panel in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jdialog

i have jdialog. and i have added 50 buttons inside a jpanel in the jdialog.
Now i want to get the values of the buttons which is set by button.setText()
now my code looks like this

```
Component[] all_comp=mydialog.getComponents();  
for(int i=0;i<=all_comp.length;i++)
        {
Container ct=all_comp[i].getParent();
String panel_name=ct.getName();
        }
```

i tried my best to find out all possible ways like taking all other functions of the component class.
but no result.
now i want to get the value of the buttons.(like button.getText).
how to do that??

Comment: JButtons are not direct children. You need to look deeper recursively.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to do is pass `mydialog` into a method that will find all of the JButtons that are contained in it. Here is a method where if you pass in a `Container` (`JDialog` is a `Container`) and a `List` it will fill up the `List` with all of the `JButtons` the `JDialog` contains regardless of how you added the `JButtons`.

```
private void getJButtons(Container container, List<JButton> buttons) {
  if (container instanceof JButton) {
    buttons.add((JButton) container);
  } else {
    for (Component component: container.getComponents()) {
      if (component instanceof Container) {
        getJButtons((Container) component, buttons);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically this method looks to see if the `Container` passed in is a `JButton`. If it is then it adds it to the `List`. If it isn't then it looks at all the children of the `Container` and recursively calls `getJButtons` with the Container. This will search the entire tree of UI components and fill up the `List` with all `JButtons` it finds.

This is kind of ugly to have to create a `List` and pass it into the `getButtons` method so we will create a wrapper method that looks nicer

```
public List<JButton> getJButtons(Container container) {
  List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
  getJButtons(container, buttons);
  return buttons;
}
```

This convenience method simply creates your `List` for you, passes it to our recursive method and then returns the `List`.

Now that we have the recursive method and the convenience method we can call the convenience method to get a list of all of our `JButton`s. After that we just loop over the items in the list and call `getText()` or whatever else you want to do with your buttons:

```
for (JButton button: getJButtons(mydialog)) {
  String text = button.getText();
  ...
}
```

Comment: cant get it plz explain or any other solution there?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check whether current component is a button. If it is, cast it to button and call its `getText()`:

```
Component[] all_comp=mydialog.getComponents();  
for(int i=0;i<=all_comp.length;i++) {
    if (all_comp[i] instanceof Button) { 
        String text = ((Button)all_comp[i]).getText();
        // this is the text. Do what you want with it....
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working because getText is not a method of component class that's why showing error